# mailgun api calls to add a domain to mailgun fail, why?

Tags: subdomain, mailgun

My api calls to add a domain fail, assuming my apikey is right why would it tell me my
     parameters passed to the API are invalid?  I followed the example code at http://documentation.mailgun.com/api-domains.html#example -- Adding a domain.  Do I have to have an smtp-password already set or am I adding a new one with the call?

My code:

```
    $mgClient = new Mailgun($this->getMailgunAPIKey());

    $domain = $this->getMailgunDomain();

    # Issue the call to the client.
    $result = $mgClient->post("domains", array(
          'name' => 'outbondxxx.mydomeainxxx.com',
          'smtp_password' => 'cagfavapassword'));
```

Thanks

PS opened a support ticket  with mailgun about this.

Comment: General note for those looking for more detailed Mailgun API error output (incl. "invalid parameters"), see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483155/mailgun-sendmessage-parameter-exception/28495484#28495484

Answer (score 0):

The password you are settings with the `smtp_password` property is the *new* password for using SMTP with the *new* domain you specify.

For debugging you could try to add the domain manually using cURL eg. to verify that the API keys etc. you are using are in fact correct.

Starting this debugging route I would recommend trying the *data fetching* calls first to verify correct setup - you could simply try querying for registered domains first using your credentials and `GET` the `/domains` endpoint.